# Bootstrap3 nav bar is not getting collapsed in iPhone 5C after loaded as xcode application?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, xcode, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented code for nav bar in bootstrap and its working fine with collapsed nav bar in iPhone 5c when I open the URL in safari browser. But when I create an xcode application with all the web content files included, and run in web view, nav bar is not getting collapsed.

Note :

1. Using Xcode 6.1
2. Bootstrap 3.3
3. Device is iPhone 5c
4. Type of application is Universal App

when I debug, no errors are shown. No files are missing.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I found the problem finally. Problem was the size of the xib file. Changed the size of xib file to my iPhone screen resolution and it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem finally. Problem was the size of the xib file. Changed the size of xib file to my iPhone screen resolution and it started working